# Прибавить временной интервал к текущей дате

Tags: java, время, datetime, jodatime

Я пытаюсь найти сумму двух периодов Joda Period. В одном периоде хранится текущая дата и время, а во втором интервал.

Первый период **date** - текущая дата и время

```
Date ddate = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Period date = new Period(fin.parsePeriod(dateFormat.format(ddate)));
```

Второй период **interval** - временной интервал формата yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

```
Period interval = new Period();

//0000-00-20 11:50:00
interval = interval.plusDays(20);
interval = interval.plusHours(11);
interval = interval.plusMinutes(50);
```

Прибавляю **interval** к **date**.

```
date = date.plus(interval);
date = date.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
```

Например, 2017-03-14 15:18:13 + 0000-00-20 11:50:00 = 2017-04-04 03:08:13 (вроде как)

Но при вывод такой: 2017-03-35 03:08:13

Как бороться с переполнением? Или может есть другой, более правильный и лаконичный подход к задаче?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте в качестве даты начала использовать не [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), а [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html):

```
 DateTime date = new DateTime();
 date = date.plus(interval);
```

`Period` — это промежуток времени. Соответственно, при сложении двух промежутков, все поля складываются раздельно и друг на друга не влияют. В частности, дни не влияют на месяцы.

2017 лет, 3 месяца и 14 дней плюс 20 дней = 2017 лет 3 месяца и 34 дня. Перенос по месяцам выполнить невозможно, т.к. дата отсчета и, соответственно, текущий месяц неизвестны.

Аналогично, 30 часов это не 1 день и 6 часов, 366 дней — не один год и день.

Comment: Помогло! Спасибо за ответ и подробное объяснение!